# split a data frame with duplicate splits and name the new list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
   cat        split_me       
   <chr>      <chr>          
 1 MVHYM7693B c(1, 7)        
 2 ZRRBS1363E c(2, 7, 18)    
 3 ZXYLV2407F 3              
 4 HXPPE8608M 4              
 5 JDARX0644Q c(5, 19)       
 6 HDBOK8136L 6              
 7 DCJPS0833K c(1, 2, 7, 18)
```

I can use the following to split the data:

```
splt <- to_split %>% 
  split(.$split_me)
```

Which gives me a list of 19 elements. However the original data had 20 elements. The split which repeats itself is split `c(5, 19)`. How can I ignore this repetition and split `c(5, 19)` twice?

I want to name the splits according to the `cat` column in `to_split` Therefore `c(5, 19)` will have different names (`JDARX0644Q`) and (`BZRXF3978Z`).

Data:

```
to_split <- structure(list(cat = c("MVHYM7693B", "ZRRBS1363E", "ZXYLV2407F", 
"HXPPE8608M", "JDARX0644Q", "HDBOK8136L", "DCJPS0833K", "UGDYS1458B", 
"ROQIP3617B", "HZMGG4347S", "EHESH8836T", "YGXZY0073I", "NMRDZ9798F", 
"WXBKD9937H", "JEMQK6388P", "QQMSV0889M", "IBMJM4467Q", "IOIDB2993Q", 
"BZRXF3978Z", "NJLNW3044Z"), split_me = c("c(1, 7)", "c(2, 7, 18)", 
"3", "4", "c(5, 19)", "6", "c(1, 2, 7, 18)", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "c(13, 18)", "14", "15", "16", "17", "c(2, 7, 13, 18)", 
"c(5, 19)", "20")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

EDIT:

What I think is best for my data is to re-order the `split_me` column. At the moment the data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   cat        split_me       
   <chr>      <chr>          
 1 MVHYM7693B c(1, 7)        
 2 ZRRBS1363E c(2, 7, 18)    
 3 ZXYLV2407F 3              
 4 HXPPE8608M 4              
 5 JDARX0644Q c(5, 19)       
 6 HDBOK8136L 6              
 7 DCJPS0833K c(1, 2, 7, 18) 
 8 UGDYS1458B 8              
 9 ROQIP3617B 9              
10 HZMGG4347S 10             
11 EHESH8836T 11             
12 YGXZY0073I 12             
13 NMRDZ9798F c(13, 18)      
14 WXBKD9937H 14             
15 JEMQK6388P 15             
16 QQMSV0889M 16             
17 IBMJM4467Q 17             
18 IOIDB2993Q c(2, 7, 13, 18)
19 BZRXF3978Z c(5, 19)       
20 NJLNW3044Z 20
```

Here `1` in the `c(1, 7)` corresponds to row 1 of the data and `7` corresponds to row `7`. I think I should re-arrange the column such that:

row `2` does not change. I.e. `c(2, 7, 18)` - the `2` is first and thus does not need to change. Row `5` also does not change since the `5` in the `c(5, 19)` is first and matches the row number `5`.

Row `7` changes. Originally it is `c(1, 2, 7, 18)` however `7` is the third in the sequence, I want to move it to the first. So `c(7, 1, 2, 18)`.

Row `13` does not change.
Row 18 changes - original `c(2, 7, 13, 18)` desired output `c(18, 2, 7, 13)`
Row 19 changes - original `c(5, 19)` desired output `c(19, 5)`.

This should fix the duplicate issue and problems I have later on with the code. For example I am trying to get it such that for splits `c(5, 19)`: the data contained in `5` will be `arranged` or above the data in `19` (in a data frame). Then for split `c(19, 5)` the data in `19` will be above the data in `5`. (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: But `to_split$split_me` is just a character vector and not actual numbers to order them.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to use `str_replace_all(split_me, "c|\\(|\\)|,", "")` and `str_replace_all(split_me, " ", "_")` to clean the data up a little and then re-arrange the order.

Comment: I think this is becoming a different question. I will have a think about how to solve it and if I cannot I will post another question later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` based on `cat` column which will automatically name the list with `cat`

```
split(to_split, to_split$cat)
```

In `dplyr` that can be done using `group_split` but it would require to add names separately

```
library(dplyr)
to_split %>% group_split(cat) %>% setNames(to_split$cat)
```

Comment: In my understanding there can be duplicates in `cat` which need to be split differently based on `split_me` var

Comment: @Sotos I am not sure because OP also mentions that `I want to name the splits according to the cat column in to_split` which means if there are similar value in `cat` column they should be in the same list ?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know. Maybe I overthought it

Comment: Thanks! both of you. The answers helped a lot. Given both your answers I actually think what is best is to re-order the `split_me` column in the data frame. Which will avoid the duplicated. I will make an edit to the original post now.

Comment: Okay, I made an edit to the original post which I think will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try pasting and then splitting so `cat` will also be included, i.e.

```
split(to_split, do.call(paste, to_split))
```

which has length of 20,

```
length(split(to_split, do.call(paste, to_split)))
#[1] 20
```

Here it is with `dplyr` method,

```
library(dplyr)

to_split %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 group_split()
```

The names after the `do.call(...)` split are of the form `cat split_me`. To name the list based only on your `cat` variable, then we can do,

```
setNames(the_list_after_spliting, to_split$cat)
```

However, If you have overall duplicates then,

```
setNames(the_list_after_spliting, 
         to_split$cat[!duplicated(do.call(paste,to_split))])
```